# How can I display html tags inside an HTML document?

Tags: html, pre

I simply want to create something like that:

```
<strong>blah blah</strong>
```

I've been trying to do this for a long time though for some reason whenever I put the code and the pre tags they don't do what they should. 
They do unformat the content - I don't see any formatting, though the tags don't appear. For example, I wrote :

```
<pre><b>abc</b></pre>
```

The abc is appearing not bold, but I can't see the tag itself. How can I do that?
I don't want to use entities like &fdaf; because I am not writing the incoming text

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What is your input and what is the result being shown? Do you want it to print just "abc" in bold or in bold and courier or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mario I think this question is very clear. Ariel wants to print "<b>abc</b>".

Comment: check solution at the bottom from fuzzyanalysis, using <xmp> tags - though it is not even html 4 compliant, it worked for my purpose (not displaying on a live site)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like mkluwe also said, you should use JavaScript (or a server-side script) to properly escape any user input. Here's another JavaScript function you could try:

```
String.prototype.escapeHTML = function () {                                        
  return(                                                                 
    this.replace(/>/g,'&gt;').
         replace(/</g,'&lt;').
         replace(/"/g,'&quot;')
  );
};
var codeEl = document.getElementById('test');
if (codeEl) {
  codeEl.innerHTML = codeEl.innerHTML.escapeHTML();
}
```

I haven't tested this in IE, but it should work there in theory. Here's a page where you can view the results: http://jsbin.com/oruri5/2/edit

Comment: @CyleHunter Agreed! Doing this server-side would be my preference & recommendation too. However, I wanted to propose a solution with working code, and since I didn't know if Ariel's setup allowed for server-side code I went with JS.

Comment: Sorry for a very basic question: Is it possible to include this anywhere on a page inside a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag? And does this method still work in modern browsers?

Answer (score 25):

Use the `<xmp>` tag, *e.g.*

```
<xmp>
  <html>
    <body>This is my html inside html.</body>
  </html>
</xmp>
```

You can also add styles and formatting inside `<xmp>` as well.

Comment: Hey this works! Contrary to all the above assertions that you *have* to do regex or replace!

Comment: This is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)

Answer (score 19):

How about replacing the incoming texts by `&lt;` and `&gt;` The tags should be visible in source view, but not "in normal view".

Comment: Thanks for the downvote...My answer isn't wrong at all. It's just not possible otherwise. So downvote as you like. There's no way around replacing the < and > with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: Why do people ask questions then downvote the correct answer? Denial of how HTML is rendered lol

Comment: @Ariel, I do believe both of these answers are technically correct. A comment or clarification that you're looking for a solution that isn't manual would be much more friendly than a cold downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything at all. I understand that's the asnwer. Why accusing? I just got back.

Answer (score 9):

You could use some javascript to change elements on the fly.

If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.org):

```
$( 'pre' ).text( $( 'pre' ).html() );
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I know is to replace the < and > with &lt; and &gt; that way it's not html anymore.  There are several other codes like these for & symbols, etc.

Where is the text coming from?  If it's in javascript than you're easiest way would be to do a regex replace in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to write stuff like &fdaf; because the browser refuses to believe that you mean <pre> for everything. This is the correct behavior, else how would you ever escape from a <pre> section? You have to go through the doc and for every less-than sign substitute &lt;. You ***do not have to do that*** for the greater-than sign or for ampersand (usually).

Comment: Oh, I see. You don't want to believe a correct answer so you downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<xmp>`, `<plaintext>` and `<listing>`. Use as suggested by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp):

> Use the `<pre>` element or, if semantically adequate, the `<code>` element instead. Note that you will need to escape the `<` character as `&lt;` to make sure it is not interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 0):

to build on @mkluwe's answer, here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/l/1/2/3" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://localhost:3000/b/1/2/3/4" target="_blank">
      </a>
    </pre>
    <script>
      $( 'pre' ).text( $( 'pre' ).html() );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```