# How to insert this text: "<p>Coder and developer</p>" inside an HTML <p></p> tag?

Tags: html, css, text, tags, paragraph

I'm just starting around with HTML and CSS and I have a probably stupid question but I that I haven't found an answer for.

Lets say I want to show this on my website:

```
<p>Coder and developer</p>
```

as simple as that, but when I write that inside the `<p>` tag it recognise the other `<p>` tag that I want to use just as text.

Probably the solution is very straight forward but I haven't found it yet as I said.

Comment: Escape the <>/ with appropriate char code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display html tags inside an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406373/how-can-i-display-html-tags-inside-an-html-document)

Comment: Use this handy tool https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be done this way using `<pre> </pre>` tag:

```html
<pre>&lt;p&gt;Coder and developer&lt;/p&gt;</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add a "p" tag in between another p tag.
HTML couldn't parse it.

If you want to create above template then use a "div" and then insert a "p" tag into it.